# how to make a partial update of an akita store state?

Tags: angular-akita

Very basic question, google didnt help.

I have an akita store for my main session. It has this state

```
    export interface SessionState {
      language: Language;
      activeRepo: number;
      auth_token: string;
      user : AppUser
      userRepos : UserRepo[]
    }
```

How can I, in the services, update just a single of these properties? For instance,"userRepos" only

i have this service call

```
 getUserRepos() {
      return httpclient.post("User","GetRepos", {}).pipe(tap<UserRepo[]>(repos  => {
           // THIS IS THE LINE THAT I CANNOT GET TO WORK--->
             this.sessionStore.update({...userRepos : repos});
      }));
 }
```

I've tried many constructions and I just cant get it.
Is it possible at all to update just a piece of the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make a POST request to update Akita state. You can use [javascript destructuring](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/) to update just that one attribute of your store. Like this:

```js
    this._sessionStore.update(state => ({
      ...state,
      userRepos: repos,
    }));
```

This takes the state object and assigns the same previous state value (destructured) changing the userRepos attribute with the one passed.

Comment: Quick question, what if the I want go deeper, for example inside UserRepos, lets say there is another interface e.g: UserSomthing, what is the best way to save into state?

Comment: You can keep destructuring
`this._sessionStore.update(state => ({
      ...state,
      userRepos: { ...state.userRepos, repos },
    }));`

Answer (score 1):

```
getUserRepos() {
 return httpclient.post("User","GetRepos", {}).pipe(tap<UserRepo[]>(repos  => {
      this.sessionStore.update({ userRepos: repos});
 }));
 }
```

Just remove the spread.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. I actually think this is correct. Akita does partial updates of objects always by itself, so no destructuring/spread needed in simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

For EntityStore an update() function exists with different variation.

```
myStore.update(currentValue => {
      return {
        propery1: {
          ...currentValue.propery1,
          propertyWithUpdate: {
            ...currentValue.propery1.propertyWithUpdate,
            field1: "new_value1",
            field5: "new_value5"
          }
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Akita has a method that does exactly that, it partially updates the store by using upsert. Upsert will update the store with given parameter, or it will create the entity if there is nothing to update because given ID doesnt exist in case you tried to update something that doesnt exist. Example of the code:

```
getUserInformation(id: string): Observable<UserInformation> {
    this.userInformationStore.setLoading(true);

    return this.userInformationProxy.getUserInformation(id).pipe(
      tap((userInformation: UserInformation) => {
        this.userInformationStore.upsert(id, userInformation);
        this.userInformationStore.setError(null);
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        this.userInformationStore.setError(error);
        return throwError(error);
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        this.userInformationStore.setLoading(false);
      })
    );
  }
```